# How can I extract dictionary values from user input

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary I dataframed using Pandas:

```
`myDict = {
  "Wakanda Burger": 4.99,
  "Tony Fries": 2.99,
  "Hulk Shake": 4.55
}

df = pd.DataFrame([myDict])
print(df)`
```

Im trying to extract the prices from the keys and depending on which item the user chose it would add it to the subtotal. This is what I tried:

```
def user_order():
  subTotal = 0
  order = input("Hi, Welcome to Marvel Eateries. What would you like?: ")
  while order not in myDict.keys():
    order = input('Item not found. Try again: ')
  
  while order in myDict.keys():
    anyElse = input(f"Perfect, {order} has been added to your order. Anything else?: ")
    subTotal = subTotal + order.myDict.values()
  
  `
    if anyElse.startswith('n').endswith('o'):
      print(f"Splendid, your total is {subTotal}.")
      break
  
    while anyElse.starswith('y').endswith("s"):
      anyElse = input('What would you like?: ')
      
  return subTotal
```

Error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'myDict'`

I am aware there is a similar post. It does not answer my question with user input.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is this line:

```
subTotal = subTotal + order.myDict.values()
```

You have to do the following to get the value from `myDict`:

```
subTotal = subTotal + myDict[order]
```

You can read more on python dictionaries [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You could try change the way that you are using to access to the dictionary, below there is an example, you could check if that works for you, if it isn't you could post the error that you get and the rest of the code.

Also you can check this [web-page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries_access.asp) and [this](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/dacp-python-fundamentals/modules/dscp-python-dictionaries/cheatsheet) to know more about it.

```
myDict = {
  "Wakanda Burger": 4.99,
  "Tony Fries": 2.99,
  "Hulk Shake": 4.55
}

df = pd.DataFrame([myDict])
print(df)


def user_order():
  subTotal = 0
  order = input("Hi, Welcome to Marvel Eateries. What would you like?: ")
  while order not in myDict.keys():
    order = input('Item not found. Try again: ')
  
  while order in myDict.keys():
    anyElse = input(f"Perfect, {order} has been added to your order. Anything else?: ")
    subTotal = subTotal + myDict[order] # changed this line
  
    if anyElse.startswith('n') or anyElse.endswith('o'): # changed this line
      print(f'Splendid, your total is {subTotal}.') # added f-string
      break
  
    while anyElse.startswith('y') or anyElse.endswith("s"): # changed this line
      order = input('What would you like?: ') # changed this line
      
  return subTotal
```